# App unresponsiveness , made up of pure python, Customtkinter GUI

Tags: python, automation, customtkinter

I've build a desktop app in pure python which notifies me a kind act to do every day on a specified time by me. The problem I'm facing is that the app gets unresponsive when I try to stop(toggle off) the backend execution of scheduling and notifying which is basically stopping the thread in which it is executed. The app works fine when I try to execute it. It just gets unresponsive when I try to stop it. The part of code I think is causing the problem is as follows:

1.toggle in the GUI

```
self.submit_toggle=ctk.CTkSwitch(master=self.page3_frame,switch_height=20,height=30,width=60,text='',command=self.backend_integration)
     self.submit_toggle.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
```

2.Backend Integration with the GUI

```
# Method to integrate Backend
    def backend_integration(self):
       self.current_value=self.submit_toggle.get()
       if self.current_value==1:
          self.preferred_time=self.User_input.get('0.0','end')
         
          self.backend = KindnessBackend(
          file_path='C:/Users/ayush/OneDrive/Desktop/Act Of Kindness Genrator/kind_acts.txt',
          config_file_path='C:/Users/ayush/OneDrive/Desktop/Act Of Kindness Genrator/user_config.json'
          )
          self.user_config=self.backend.load_user_config()
          self.user_config['Enter The Preferred Time For Notification'] =self.preferred_time
          self.backend.save_user_config(self.user_config)
          self.backend_thread=threading.Thread(target=self.delaying_backend)
          self.backend_thread.start()
       else:
          pass
          self.stop_backend()
          
          

    def stop_backend(self):
       if self.backend_thread and self.backend_thread.is_alive():
         self.backend.stop()
         self.backend_thread.join()
```

3.Scheduling and Notifying functions in the Backend code

```
def print_random_act(self):
        user_config = self.load_user_config()
        preferred_time = user_config.get("Enter The Preferred Time For Notification", "11:00")

        with open(self.file_path, 'r') as file:
            kind_acts = file.read().splitlines()

        if kind_acts:
            selected_act = random.choice(kind_acts)
            kind_acts.remove(selected_act)
            notification.notify("Today's Act of Kindness is:", message=selected_act, timeout=10)
        else:
            notification.notify("Congrats!!,You've completed 500 Acts of Kindness!!", timeout=10)
          
            

    def schedule_backend(self):
        user_config = self.load_user_config()
        preferred_time = user_config.get("Enter The Preferred Time For Notification", "11:00")
        self.schedule_job=schedule.every().day.at(preferred_time).do(self.print_random_act)
        def schedule_task():
          while True:
           schedule.run_pending()
           time.sleep(5)
        threading.Thread(target=schedule_task(), daemon=True).start()    
        

    def stop(self):
        self.running=False
```

[To access the whole code, visit my Github Repo](https://github.com/AyushMayekar/Act-Of-Kindness-Generator)

[Connect with me on linkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/in/ayush-mayekar-b9b883284/?utm_source=share&utm_campaign=share_via&utm_content=profile&utm_medium=android_app)

[This is the image when the app gets unresponsive due to toggling off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAj0c.png)

I'm a student and learning python, this project was an opportunity and an experiment through which I learnt a lot. I tried different approaches ,but I guess the problem in Multithreading is what I am facing. I don't know if it is fixable or not. I am expecting my app to stop whenever I toggle off and start execution whenever I a toggle on. The app should notify me even when it is closed, it should stop notifying me only when I toggle off. It should basically work like an alarm app but only with a difference of notification rather than music.